# How to take advantage of Quarkus in existing spring boot applications

Tags: quarkus

How to take advantage of Quarkus in existing spring boot microservices.

I could not find documentation on how to use it for spring framework applications.

Comment: This is an off-topic question and should be closed because it's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Boot applications will *not* work on Quarkus. Quarkus is a different framework that currently supports [Spring Dependency Injection](https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-di-guide) annotations, and the most important functionality of [Spring Web](https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-web-guide) and [Spring Data JPA](https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-data-jpa-guide).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Quakus has an embedded container like spring boot to serve rest end points ?

Comment: Quarkus leverages Undertow as its embedded web server (Undertow is also an option in Spring Boot of course).

Comment: If you want to create REST endpoints, then Quarkus has RESTEasy for JAX-RS endpoints

Answer (score 2):

It is also an option to migrate Spring Boot application to Quarkus. You can find [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring2quarkus-spring-boot-to-quarkus-migration) a detailed guide based on the real migration on one of my microservices: https://dzone.com/articles/spring2quarkus-spring-boot-to-quarkus-migration